# Transitioning from Java to Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am writing a Java program for my workplace, to help catalog pricing with several parameters involved.  The current program implements `JComboBox`, along with other Container objects.

I have realized that our workstation will not run a Java program through Windows due to protective limitations, so I am hoping to transition to Go`ogle App Engine`, since we can load websites much more freely.

The problem I have run into is that `JComboBox` doesn't run through Google App Engine.  In fact, none of the Containers I was using will work in Google App Engine.  The tutorials on Google Developers haven't provided the information I need.

Where can I find information on what objects I can use in `Google App Engine` to simulate a GUI with pop-up menus and buttons?

(I am using the Google Plugin for Eclipse.)

Comment: GAE is a *web* framework. You have to output HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link will help you, it lists all compatible frameworks: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

For a higly responsive GUI, I suggest you take a look at the GWT: http://www.gwtproject.org/examples.html

In a nutshell: GWT allows you to write web applications with Java. Some/all of the Java is converted into JavaScript for better usability.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like what I'm needing.  And now begins the arduous process of collecting data at work and coding at home...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Google App Engine (`GAE`) you can either use GWT for a standard GUI or a Java Webframework like Vaadin or JSF.